# Ripple not drawable over other view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view and I am inflating another view as an item of this recycler view. Certain padding/margin is needed for each item on left and right, but I want the ripple to be visible on the complete width of the screen (recycler view width is fit to screen).

Code -

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:paddingStart="20dp"
      android:paddingEnd="20dp"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:clipChildren="false"
      android:clipToPadding="false"/>

Recycler View Item XML

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
...

</LinearLayout>
```

From this code, ripple extends only till Recycler View Item XML width.

I have tried moving this padding to Recycler View Item XML and it works. But is there any other option to this, I basically don't want to move paddingStart and paddingEnd.

I have tried all of these -

1. android:background="@android:color/transparent"
2. android:clipChildren="false"
   android:clipToPadding="false"
3. android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"

Comment: make sure your recyclerview item  layout not have any padding and use background as  
 ?attr/selectableItemBackground

Comment: Not using any padding there, and I don't think it should affect that. I have tried using selectableItemBackground

Comment: what happens ? are you testing on >21 device?

Comment: Ripple is not extending to complete screen. Yes.

Comment: can you please share item layout xml?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your recyclerview item layout not have any margin and have width to  match parent

Add parent item layout background like below

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```